# how to resolve the object variable or with block variable not set in this code

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub WebTry()

Dim objIE As Object 'special object variable representing the IE browser
Dim l As Object 'special object variable for an <a> (link) element

Set objIE = CreateObject("INTERNETEXPLORER.Application")

objIE.Visible = True

sUser = "username"
sPass = "password"

objIE.navigate "https://mywebsitecomeshere"

Do While objIE.busy = True Or objIE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


objIE.document.all.Item("USER").Value = sUser
objIE.document.all.Item("PASSWORD").Value = sPass
objIE.document.all.Item("loginbtn").Click
Do While objIE.busy = True Or objIE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

objIE.document.all.Item("image5").Click
Do While objIE.busy = True Or objIE.readystate <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

End
```

Error is coming when it comes to `objIE.document.all.Item("image5").Click` line.
My actual requirement is, it will login into a website (using the credentials). Then it should automatically click another button (`<img id="image5" src="https://abc/cde/efg" alt="Time" name="image5"> </img>`) in the website.
Please help as I'm new to VBA, 
Thanks in advance

Comment: HTML Source: <img id="image5" src="https://abc/cde/efg" alt="Time" name="image5"> </img>

Comment: Is there a link or action defined for the image? Have you tried calling this methoed instead the click on the image? What happens, if the image is clicked?
Maybe try this: 'objIE.Document.getElementById("image5").getElementsByTagName("img")(0).Click'

Comment: And when you put a break point after the row `objIE.document.all.Item("loginbtn").Click` what do you see? In your question you didn't say what should happen after the `loginbtn` was clicked. I assume next page is loaded with the `image5`. So what happens after click is called from VBA code, does the next page show up? Maybe the `objIE.document.all.Item("loginbtn").Click` didn't work and IE document is still pointing to login page?

Comment: After clicking Login button, my desired website will be launched where in which I am trying to click another image, once I click the image (image5)...lower section of the page will be reloaded and it will show the fields to enter data

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error before using VB/VBA to access IE elements before the document has fully loaded. Apparently the readystate property doesn't always work the way you think it should.

The safest way to click an element that should be in the document is to wait until it can actually be referenced.

As a safeguard, from the off-chance the object has been renamed or doesn't acually exist, you should limit to the loop to 3 tries or so.

**At the top of your module insert the delay function:**

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
```

**Before you click the image with this line:**

```
objIE.document.all.Item("image5").Click
```

**Add this code that checks for element ID:**

```
Dim numTries As Integer
Do While IsNull(objIE.Document.getelementbyid("image5"))
   numTries = numTries + 1
   If numTries > 3 Then Exit Do
   DoEvents
   Sleep 1000 ' Delay one second
Loop
If IsNull(objIE.Document.getelementbyid("image5")) Then
    Msgbox "No Image5 Found"
Endif
```

Comment: On adding the line Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) I am getting the error like "Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, End Property".

Unable to do anything.. if someone can help me please let me know we will get on to a call. Thanks in advance

Comment: Good to hear from you again... Did you read the bolded instruction: **At the top of your module insert the delay function:** - emphasis should have been "AT THE TOP OF YOUR MODULE"